# Propel understanding peers

Tags: orm, symfony1, propel

I'm using symfony 1.4, and am fairly new to propel.  I'm looking at an existing codebase in a new project, written by other developers.

In layman's terms, what is the purpose of having a model separated into two classes, the *model*, and *modelPeer classes*??

I would assume that one gets business type data and the other represents more of a data layer, but I dont see any type of distinction when examining the two classes.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just think of it as the row (model) and the table (peer). Simplistic, but a few beginners got the idea after I've explained it like this :)

Comment: Thanks. Coming in on a legacy 1.2 Symfony project and this got me going

Comment: Omg if someone just told me this a week ago. Amazing explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's better to forget Peer classes. My advice is to never use them - Peer classes will be removed in Propel2 anyway.

Then, you just have to deal with an ActiveRecord API (model classes) and an ActiveQuery API.

Edit: read https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/issues/36 to know what Peers handle. As a developer, you should **not** put any code in this part. AR and AQ are more than enough.

Comment: -1, sorry. If the OP is using Propel 1.x, then peers are essential - one cannot use this series of Propel without using or understanding them! Peers are used to hold table/column names, and are used statically to call table-wide database operations, such as `doSelect`.

Comment: No, Peers are **not** essential since ActiveQuery is  provided. And you dont need to deal with these classes. I know what are Peer classes, check my profile...

Comment: Hi William. When you say your advice is to never use them, do you mean *don't put code in them*? As far as I can tell it isn't possible to avoid *using* peers in Propel 1.x. Can I look up a column or table name using the Query classes, for example, without using `MyPeer::TABLE_NAME` or `MyPeer::COLUMN_NAME`? Can I obtain the related TableMap for a table without using the Peer (`MyPeer::getTableMap()`)? I ask partly because it'd be great to tweak my current coding to avoid peers, but I'm presently of the view that some instances are inevitable.

Comment: I take your point about doSelect not being necessary, as the chainable query class can be (should be :-) used instead.

Comment: Hi @william-durand: can I press you for an answer on the above question? I think it would be of benefit to the wider community. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I mean don't put code in Peer classes. I personally never put code in them, even with symfony 1.x. The `ModelCritera` has a `getTableMap()` method for instance.

Comment: OK, thanks, -1 reverted. Do you write all your table/column names as string literals? I *always* use the constants so I get a warning if I make a typo.

Comment: I try to avoid using table/column names as string or constants. But you're probably right for constants, Peers should be used, it's often better to use constants instead of string literals. Anyway, it's quite specific as to use raw table/column names isn't a common use case IMO

Comment: I agree - it's just I've seen quite a few cases of ActiveQuery clauses using string literals in the wild - had wondered if this was a recommended approach :)